# Teacher's dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Intro: I am trying to create a function named num_teachers that takes a single argument, which will be a dictionary of teachers and their courses.
The num_teachers function should return an integer for how many teachers are in the dict.

What I have done:

```
def num_teachers(t_list):
    count = 0
    t_list = {'Andrew Chalkley': ['jQuery Basics', 'Node.js Basics'],'Kenneth Love': ['Python Basics', 'Python Collections']}

    for t in t_list:
        if t in t_list.keys():  
            count += 1
        else:
            count = 1
    return t_list
```

Question:
At this point I am not sure what to call to return an integer for how many teachers are in the dict. Is for loop set up correctly? What I am missing?

Comment: Your parameter `t_list` is overwritten by the definition `t_list = {...}`. There is only one variable named `t_list` in this code, not two.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the loop consider to simply:

`return len(t_list)`.

Read about [len()](https://tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_len.htm).